# Missing Sent Items on Exchange Server

Tags: exchange-2003

I'm having a bit of an issue with my Exchange server.

While it's quite minor, I would like the issue resolved. Some of the Sent Items appear to be missing from my database. I noticed it first when sending out an inter-office email that consisted ONLY of internal contacts. The message is not in my Sent Items on OWA or Outlook...yet the users all got it and it's in the Message Tracking Center of the ESM.

Another user has just told me that she's noticed the same issue on her computer...Can anybody think of a reason this may be happening?

I have only noticed an issue with "Sent Items" and nothing else. We have the Enterprise Version of Exchange 2003 w/ SP2 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if only you and another staff has this problem, then run outlook without rules (if any) to see whether this happens or not.

usually emails disappear when outlook rules go corrupt, as per your question, as it is only you and another member experiencing - i would check outlook rules first, basically start outlook without rules
[Outlook 2003 command line switches](http://www.techgalaxy.net/Docs/Exchange/OL2003_switches.htm)

`outlook /cleanrules`
the above will delete all rules and start outlook

Comment: Now that you mention it, I recall seeing a few "Rules" warnings on my exchange server...Is it safe to assume that these emails are gone for good? They don't seem to be in the "Recover deleted e-mails" section either.

Comment: run outlook with clean rules, they might appear (but no guarantee), i had a few occasions where they re-appeared as they were delivered / saved in different folders.

Comment: Thank you for your responses - I've cleared my rules but the other person who noticed the issue sent her email from a Blackberry while overseas and her computer was off (which I presume means her account didn't have access to her Outlook rules)

Answer (score 0):

Putting things into Sent Items is a client feature, not a server feature. I think it sounds like there's something wrong with Outlook, rather than a server problem. The server has obviously processed the mail properly, so I'd go with the Rules problem on Outlook too.